# cov(A, mean=0) gives InexactError

Tags: statistics, julia

I am getting `InexactError()` when calculating the covariance of rows in a matrix when setting `mean=0`:

```
julia> A = [1 -1 -1; -1 1 1; -1 1 -1; 1 -1 -1; 1 -1 1]
5x3 Array{Int64,2}:
  1  -1  -1
 -1   1   1
 -1   1  -1
  1  -1  -1
  1  -1   1

julia> cov(A) # Works
3x3 Array{Float64,2}:
  1.2  -1.2  -0.2
 -1.2   1.2   0.2
 -0.2   0.2   1.2

julia> cov(A, mean=[0. 0. 0.]) # Works
3x3 Array{Float64,2}:
  1.25  -1.25  -0.25
 -1.25   1.25   0.25
 -0.25   0.25   1.25

julia> cov(A, mean=0) # Expecting same output as above
ERROR: InexactError()
 in generic_scale! at linalg/generic.jl:18
 in covzm at statistics.jl:253
 in cov at statistics.jl:286
```

[Docs for Base.cov](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/?highlight=cov#Base.cov) say:

> mean: allow users to supply mean values that are known. By default, it is set to nothing, which indicates that the mean(s) are unknown, and the function will compute the mean. **Users can use mean=0 to indicate that the input data are centered, and hence there’s no need to subtract the mean**.

The Julia source ([statistics.jl, line 286](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/statistics.jl#L286)) clearly tests if `mean=0` has been passed:

```
function cov(x::AbstractMatrix; vardim::Int=1, corrected::Bool=true, mean=nothing)
    mean == 0 ? covzm(x; vardim=vardim, corrected=corrected) :
    mean == nothing ? covm(x, _vmean(x, vardim); vardim=vardim, corrected=corrected) :
    isa(mean, AbstractArray) ? covm(x, mean; vardim=vardim, corrected=corrected) :
    error("Invalid value of mean.")
end
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should be considered a bug.  After having stepped through the code, the error in question occurs on line 18 of generic.jl,  in particular the following function.

```
function generic_scale!(C::AbstractArray, X::AbstractArray, s::Number)
    length(C) == length(X) || error("C must be the same length as X")
    for i = 1:length(X)
        @inbounds C[i] = X[i]*s
    end
    C
end
```

where the 3 variable form is invoked by the 2 variable form like this:

```
generic_scale!(X::AbstractArray, s::Number) = generic_scale!(X, X, s)
```

At this point, [from looking at the source](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/statistics.jl#L254), s will have value 0.25 and X will have the result of the following

```
x = unscaled_covzm(A, 1)
3x3 Array{Int64,2}:
  5  -5  -1
 -5   5   1
 -1   1   5
```

Cutting and pasting the above definition into the REPL allow one to test generic_scale directly

```
julia> generic_scale!(x,x,0.25)
ERROR: InexactError()
 in generic_scale! at none:4
```

And the reason is X is a Matrix of Int64 which causes convert to throw an inexact error because 1.25 can't be represented by an int.  If instead X were Float64 then there is no error:

```
julia> x = unscaled_covzm(A, 1)*1.0
3x3 Array{Float64,2}:
  5.0  -5.0  -1.0
 -5.0   5.0   1.0
 -1.0   1.0   5.0

julia> generic_scale!(x,x,0.25)
3x3 Array{Float64,2}:
  1.25  -1.25  -0.25
 -1.25   1.25   0.25
 -0.25   0.25   1.25
```

And so if you define a Float64 version of A from your example

```
julia> B=A*1.0
5x3 Array{Float64,2}:
  1.0  -1.0  -1.0
 -1.0   1.0   1.0
 -1.0   1.0  -1.0
  1.0  -1.0  -1.0
  1.0  -1.0   1.0

julia> cov(B,mean=0)
3x3 Array{Float64,2}:
  1.25  -1.25  -0.25
 -1.25   1.25   0.25
 -0.25   0.25   1.25
```

Comment: Thanks. So the bug is either in `unscaled_covzm` (because it should return a `Float64` array) or `generic_scale!` (because it should accept an `Int` array).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's Not the right answer. I just want to say, if you replace the 'mean=0' with 'mean=[0.]' in you lines, Julia get the following Answer. :)

```
julia> cov(A,mean=[0.])
3x3 Array{Float64,2}:
  1.25  -1.25  -0.25
 -1.25   1.25   0.25
 -0.25   0.25   1.25
```